# asyncData not displaying API results

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm quite new to making my own API's and backend. I've set up an express server that has an API call to Salesforce that returns (in the terminal):

```js
{      
  attributes: {
    type: 'Opportunity',
    url: '/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Opportunity/xxxxxxxxxxxx'
  },
  Id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
  Name: 'United Oil Standby Generators',
  StageName: 'Closed Won'
}
```

However, when I try to call the API from inside Nuxt using asyncData, it returns nothing.
Here is my asyncData:

```js
asyncData ({ params, error, $http }) {
  return $http
    .$get('/api/salesforce/' + params.id)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('here we go')
        console.log(res.json)
      return { opp: res }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'User not found, ' + e })
    })
  
},
```

When I run the page, my terminal console returns results (since I've asked the express server to do that), but when I use the Vue tools on Chrome or try to access the data, there is nothing in Opp. If I return res.json - it returns as undefined. It should be returning as .json already since I've set it in the backend.

Could anyone see where I'm going wrong here? Like I said - I'm pretty new to working with my own API's.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to let's say, a `/subjects/3` path with `_id.vue` being dynamic, you can use the following to have access to this mocked API.

You can use the following to have it displayed on the Nuxt side

```html
<template>
  <div>
    {{ opp }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ params, error, $http }) {
    try {
      const res = await $http.$get(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${params.id}`
      )
      console.log('here we go', res)
      return { opp: res }
    } catch (err) {
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: `User not found, ${err}` })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

A working github repo can be found here: https://github.com/kissu/so-nuxt-fetch

I'm not sure if there is something not working with your API, but this is how you handle this on the frontend at least.

Comment: Huh, I got the response from here. Looks like my API isn't working properly. I'm not a backend dev so this is really annoying to fix. I might ask a separate question, thanks for the help kissu!